# Fitting a More Complicated Distribution: A Mixture of Two Normals (MATLAB example)

Tags: matlab, mixture-model

I am following the MATLAB example found [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html#zmw57dd0e597)

Is the formula to estimate the startpoint for the variance of a mixture in terms of the mean and variance of each component correct?

```
sigmaStart = sqrt(var(x) - .25*diff(muStart).^2)
```

with my data I have that

```
var(x) = 0.1045
muStart = [0.7000    1.3600];
```

so that sigmaStart is non real

```
sigmaStart =    0.0000 + 0.0664i
```

Could you please help me? I attach the histogram that I want to fit..
[image]

Comment: a mixture of 2 normals = Gaussian mixture model?

Comment: I think so...this is how the example is named in the matlab webpage...

Comment: The variance value does not fit your data.

Comment: I attached the pdf of my data...I want to fit these histograms

Comment: If your `sigmaStart` is imaginary, then I think it's safe to say that your formula is not correct.

Comment: @AnderBiguri any guess about a possible variance? Would 1 be an acceptable value?

Comment: @gabboshow are you trying to fit the sum of two normal bumps with a single normal distribution...?

Comment: @gabboshow have you tried using the equation of the variance....? Imean, you dont "guess" it, you compute it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no with a mixture of normal distributions as in the example..

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes I know... but I am wondering if to compute the variance of the data for which I plotted the pdf or the variance of the histogram bars... in the first case the variance is 0.1...

Comment: yes, the Gaussian Mixture Model - you can try any value setting your start point since it iterates and converges to the right one, setting it closer to the right value simply decreases the number of iterations needed for convergence. Look at your histogram and set it based on it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri my data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OEUZHGRRZoLkRtriNhPjsLoq383c6DC5mhuLzr6G1Ic/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just use another equation for your data.

Comment: I'd answer but it's my birthday

Comment: @AnderBiguri what do you mean?

Comment: @gabboshow that is just to choose an starting point. Just choose it somehow else, e.g. 1.

Comment: @AnderBiguri well here the point is that I am following a Matlab example and trying to understand what's wrong...

Comment: @gabboshow no worries there. They just use an heuristic equation to choose an starting point, equation that can not be applied to your data because it is too different. You could also use more "mixed" data. Your data would not generally be solved with a GMM because its too separable.